# How to Protect the website DB Configuration files?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, security, magento

Recently my website has been hacked.
The hackers has injected the code in both files and Db too.
after finding this incident, I have verified my web site files and db too.
My Db configuration files has been open permission to the users, so they have got all db login information from configurations files to injected the code.

So i would like to protect my website configuration files very securely.
What is the best file permission for configuration files ?
And How to protect the websites from hacking?

Any suggestions and solutions much helpful for me.

Thanks for all !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep that file outside of your webroot as it is not required to be in your webroot for your site to function properly.

Comment: Not a standard configuration of Magento. It needs a [little hacking to do that,](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_move_local.xml_outside_the_doc_root) which will get overwritten on the next upgrade. Mmm Mangogento!